# Android Cocos2dX drawing a shape using CGPoint array

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, ccsprite

I have been working on an android game in which i need to create a image shattering effect.I am using Cocos2dx for the game development.

i have divided the shape to be shattered in to small triangles and stored them into an array,since it is in Cocos2dx the vertex array is a CGPoint array.
for example

```
CGPoint[] vertices;

vertices[1]={CGPoint.ccp(0,0),CGPoint.ccp(1,0),CGPoint.ccp(1,1)}

vertices[2]={CGPoint.ccp(1,0),CGPoint.ccp(0,1),CGPoint.ccp(1,1)}
....
vertices[numVertices]={CGPoint.ccp(1,0),CGPoint.ccp(0,1),CGPoint.ccp(1,1)}
```

When it comes to drawing

i have converted the vertex array into a FloatBuffer like this

```
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * 2*3* numVertices);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        triVertices = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
```

---

In onDraw() method
Here pt1,pt2,pt3 are CGPoints

```
         for(int i=0;i<numVertices;i++){

        triVertices.put(vertices[i].pt1.x);
        triVertices.put(vertices[i].pt1.y);
        triVertices.put(vertices[i].pt2.x);
        triVertices.put(vertices[i].pt2.y);
        triVertices.put(vertices[i].pt2.x);
        triVertices.put(vertices[i].pt2.y);
    }
    gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, triVertices);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, triTexCoords);
    gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, colorBuffer);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, numVertices*3);
```

---

Unfortunatly the entire shape is not getting drawn .In the sense only individual triangles are getting drawn.Is there any problem in my logic.Please help me.Its really urgent.

### Edit

Below is the code that i am using to call the shattering class **ShatteredSprite.java** which extends CCSprite.

```
    CCSprite newSprite= CCSprite.sprite("bg-hand1.jpg");
    int piecesX = 20;
    int piecesY = 20;
    float speedVar = 0.5f;
    float rotVar = 0.2f;
    boolean radial = true;
    ShatteredSprite shatter =ShatteredSprite.shatterWithSprite(newSprite,
            piecesX,
            piecesY,
            speedVar,
            rotVar,
            radial);
    shatter.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint.make(0, 0));
    shatter.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(100, 150));
    this.addChild(shatter, 1, 99);
```

Now the shattering is happening but the effect is displaying on the right top corner so only a potion of it is visible.How to make it right.Have any ideas .Thanks in advance.

Comment: apparently the array that i was passing to the buffer has some mistake .instead of CGPoint pt3 i have passed pt2 again.Now the shattering is occuring but it is misplcaed and displaying on the right top corner only, so a portion of the scattering effect is visible.How to correct that has any one have any idea?.

Comment: Can i get ur shatteredsprite.java file possible on ruchit.shah@digi-corp.com,  thanks in advance...!!!!